# Is there a way to install Python for ARM in a amd64 architecture?

Tags: python, linux, arm, cross-compiling, x86-64

I am trying to cross compile an application for arm that depends on Python2.7 headers, but as you may understand, I don't have these headers and I don't know where nor how obtain them. I tried doing something like:

```
sudo apt install libpython2.7-dev:armhf
```

But it didn't work, it can't find the package. I saw another question like this but the answer were that this isn't possible as it is a conflict (both binaries are named Python and so  on...), but it is? I just want the headers which are going to be in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include , what's the problem with that?

Also, is possible that I am wrong thinking that the solution for my problem is to install the headers, the error is the following:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:24:54: fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any other ideas than mine?

Thank you very much,
Marc

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt update
```

before you can install packages of a foreign architecture.  With these additional steps, I can install `libpython2.7-dev:armhf` on Debian stretch, but I have not verified if this actually works for compiling anything.

Comment: I already did it... And it doesn't works. Its not able to fetch the packages when I update, I found a thread which said that you had to change things in the sources.list, I did it but it says that I have held broken packages.

Comment: I think systems with the `apt` command also have `dpkg --add-architecture`.  So undo the `sources.list` modification, run `apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies, and try again?